# Using Try/Except statement in Python

Tags: python

my code is as follows:

```
import mechanize 
import urlparse
import util 

url = "https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/"
urls = [url]
visited = []
link_pdf = []
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
while len(urls) > 0: 
    try:
        br.open(urls[0])
        urls.pop(0)
        for link in br.links(): 
           new_url = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
           print new_url
           urls.append(new_url) 
    except: 
         print "error"
```

Below is how it runs: 
At some points, it will be like this:

```
https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/Publications/tvm.pdf
error
https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/Publications/vce.pdf
error
https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/Publications/mclaughlin.strain.kdv.pdf
error
error
error
error
error
error 
....
```

And I only want it print out four times

It will run and print "error" until some points that it will only print out error forever. And, I only want it hit my script hit error only four time and break it. 
hence, can anyone show me how to do it? Thank you.

EDIT: I posted the the code that cause error forever and how it runs.

Comment: Just use a counter, increment it and when it is equals to 4, break the loop.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant while

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to allow for an error only four times.

Count the number of errors you have had and let the loop end when you hit the limit.

```
errors = 0
while len(urls) > 0 and errors < 4:
    try:
        #doing something 
    except:
        errors += 1
        print "error"
```

Comment: I tried your way, but whenever it hits error, it will count up and it will never touch the point where error runs forever. My point is I want error runs forever but only 4 times and it will break the loops

Comment: Nope, I have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is in "try:" statement you do something that change the lenght of url variable. When "try:" fails to operate, len(url) stays the same for the rest of the loop(assuming you meant "while" instead of "why") and "except:" is the only part remain executing.

Without knowing the rest of the code, I cannot offer much help

Edit: You edited your post and it seems i am correct, when "try:" part fails, new url never get to assign the new url, and while enters an infinite loop where it prints "error" forever.

Comment: Oh, I just did. It is a type of web-crawler, and at some points, it will hit errorr forever

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a counter with nested while loop like this:

```
while you_cond:
    tries = 0

    while tries < 4:
        try:
            pass  # do something
            break
        except Exception:
            print('error')
            tries += 1
```

Also you can use both conditions in main while loop and omit second one (behavior will change in this case).

Comment: @Alexander then you do something wrong. Post you full code, error not in posted one.

Comment: First of all how you want to break the error? Mute it or raise? Maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: whenever, it print out
error
error
error
error
....
i only want it raise that error for only four times

Comment: at some points, it will raise error forever and I only want it raises four times and then stop the script

Comment: the code above should do this. updated example with just behavior like you have: https://gist.github.com/40367a5ce172b0c0843a and screenshot of output: http://d.pr/i/1esIn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98443/discussion-between-ssbb-and-alexander).

Answer (score 0):

The issue about your code is about invariants, namely:

```
len(urls) > 0
```

It is likely that the `try` part of the code somewhat alters the length of the urls container.

If you don't want to reach an infinite loop after the first failure, you must alter the container on the `except` part, preferably removing the item that caused the error.

I shorter words: As it stands, `len(urls)` will never change after the first error.

Then, as a Python programmer, you should know that it is best to catch the specific exceptions you might expect, and let the others pass, as the ones that pass will point to *bugs* (faults in your solution).